# Why is there a transparent rectangle behind my object?

Tags: camera

And how do I get rid of it?

This rectangle didn't exist before. I got a few renders of my work in progress in the beginning, and everything looked fine. Now I have a gray/transparent rectangle behind my objects, no matter how I try to change the background. I can only see it in camera view, and it renders in my final images as well. I currently have a big cube in which my objects are placed, and the rectangle seems to conform to the cube however I rotate it (to stay behind the camera). I've checked the normals of the cube (they're correct) and deleted it and created a new one, but the rectangle has stayed.

[image]

[image]

The cube is at a forty-five degree angle. The rectangle stays perpendicular to the camera view and fills in the corner. This is the rendered view, with Cycles. Any insight on how it got there and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Can you provide your .blend file for examination? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: camera > transparent = checked?

Comment: @sanbaldo Strangely enough, when I went to Scene > Film and unchecked Transparent, the mysterious rectangle disappeared in the rendered view (and does not render with the final image) but is still there in solid view. So it is no longer transparent, but it is still there. This is good enough for me, though!

Answer (score 1):

I think you enabled the crop to render region on the output settings[image: Shown here]

What you can do is either disable it or **ctrl + alt + b** to remove any render region crop.

To add it again, you can use **ctrl + b** and select a portion you want to render